# Spring dependency injection when number of concurrent class increase

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I want to know how spring mannage when number of concurent class that use a dependency injected class grow? Does it create a new instance! 
or how should i config to grow up speed.
Thanks

Comment: The Spring bean factory takes care of all of it.  What on earth is the question?

Comment: @NathanHughes suppose i have a Dao class that gives us list of a table data; what happen when number of class that use this Dao increass, one instance of this Dao is enough or there should be more than one instance

Answer (score 1):

> want to know how spring mannage when number of concurent class that
>   use a dependency injected class grow? Does it create a new instance!

In Spring, the bean scope is specified in this declaration : `singleton` (default value), `prototype`, and so for.
Once specified, it will not change any longer.
And that whatever the number of instances that injects the bean.